# How to use a String in a switch statement

Tags: java, queue, switch-statement

Here I'm trying to implement a simple queue using linked list. I used Bufferreader and readline here. I declared "choice" as string. But I can't pass a string variable to switch statement. If I declared it as Integer variable then readline method won't accept it. Can anyone help??

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the no of elements to be inserted: ");
    String str;
    str=bf.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Your Choice: ");
    System.out.println("1->Insert 2->Delete 3->Display 4->Exit");
    String choice;
    choice=bf.readLine();
    for(;;){
    switch(choice) {

        case 1:l1.addLast(bf);
                break;
        case 2:l1.removeFirst();
        break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("The contents of Queue are :" +l1);
            break;
        default:break;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: or change you switch case to `case "1"`,`case "2"` etc since choice is a String type

Comment: You can use `String` in a `switch` statement since Java 7, which was released a few months ago. If you're using Java 6 or older, you cannot use `String` in a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int choiceNum = Integer.parseInt(choice);` and switch on that.

Note that in Java 7 you actually can switch on Strings, but you would need to `case "1":`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay another answer keep the String:

```
if (choice.equals("1")) {
    ...
} else if (choice.equals("2")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always going to be a one character input, you can convert it to `char` and switch on that using single quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Parse the String to an integer before putting it into ta switch statement:

```
int choice;
choice = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an int, you might want to parse your String to int with [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), or use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) instead of BufferedReader to retrieve an int directly from your file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> choice = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to use a LinkedList you need to specify the data type while declaring.

```
LinkedList<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

This will create a linked list of data type Strings. Then you can use parse function to convert String into int.

```
int choice;
choice = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
```

Comment: Not necessarily. While it isn't recommended to do so, you can use a raw `LinkedList` (or any other generic). The first item you add determines the type.